# How to specify training parameters in LibSVM C# Wrapper

Tags: c#-4.0, svm, libsvm

I'm completely new to the world of SVM. I'm using LibSvmWrapper for c# from [this link](https://bitbucket.org/VahidN/libsvmwrapper)

but I can't figure out how to use it and how to specify the right parameters specially the documentation seems to be corrupted when I tried to run it using Doxygen

here is my attempt:

```
        libSVM_Problem prob = new libSVM_Problem();
        libSVM classifier = new libSVM();
        libSVM_Parameter parameters = new libSVM_Parameter();
        parameters.svm_type = libSVMWrapper.SVM_TYPE.C_SVC;
        parameters.kernel_type = KERNEL_TYPE.LINEAR;
        parameters.C = 1;

        double[] labels = new double[trainClasses.Rows];
        //prepare classes labels
        for (int i = 0; i < trainClasses.Rows; i++)
        {
            labels[i] = trainClasses[i, 0];//trainClasses is an array of floats
        }

        //prepare samples 
        double[][] samples = new double[trainData.Rows][];

        for (int i = 0; i < samples.Length; i++)
        {
            samples[i] = new double[trainData.Cols];
            for (int j = 0; j < samples[i].Length; j++)
            {
                //trainData is 980 training sample * 400 features 
                samples[i][j] = trainData[i, j];
            }
        }
        //prepare data and attach it to prob object
        prob.labels = labels;
        prob.samples = samples;
        parameters.nu = 0;
        classifier.Train(prob, parameters);
```

This code throws an exception on calling Train method which states that the weight parameter within libSVM_Parameter is null referenced. I have no idea how to specify these weights and generally the parameters of libSVM_Parameter.
So, if anyone has an example of how to specify the right parameters it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use https://github.com/ccerhan/LibSVMsharp
API for libsvm with c#.NET. It has some examples also which will help you to understand SVM too.